# jQuery accordion flash loads content only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, dom, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page/template that has an accordion, that once loaded in Google Chrome, flashes the content inside very quickly at first, and then disappears once the DOM/javascript actually loads, which reverts the page to how it's supposed to look. This problem doesn't happen in Firefox, only Chrome.

I tried adding a "jQueryElement.hide()" but all it did was hide the content completely..

Here's (stack-list-template.php) :

```
<?php
    $stackQuery = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => 'abc_stack',
                        'meta_key' => 'abc_stack_key') );

    if ( $stackQuery->have_posts() ) {
        ?><div class="accordion-header">
            <h2><i class="blue-arrow fa-long-arrow-right fa fa-2"></i> Stacks</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="stack-list-container">
        <?php
        while ( $stackQuery->have_posts() ) {
            $stackQuery->the_post();?>


                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'stack-list-template' ); ?>


        <?php } // end while
        echo "</div>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?> 

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.accordion-header').click(function() {
            jQuery(this).next().toggle('slow');
            jQuery("i",this).toggleClass("fa-long-arrow-right fa-long-arrow-down");
            return false;
        }).next('.stack-list-container').hide();
    });
</script>
```

I read here: http://www.learningjquery.com/examples/style-noflash.html

and tried implementing the "hide" technique but it only hid my content.

What's the proper way to make this above resource work with my code? What is the correct way to write that script I have so that the content inside the accordion doesn't flash upon page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content that should be hidden on page load should be hidden using CSS (or, if necessary, inline styling), because you can never be sure how long it will take the javascript to load or execute.

So either do this:

```
<div class="stack-list-container" style="display:none">
```

Or, preferably, in CSS that loads in your `<head>` element, do this:

```
.stack-list-container{ display:none; }
```

You can also delete this line, as it's now redundant:

```
.next('.stack-list-container').hide();
```

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't work. When the page loads, and I click on the arrow that would usually expand the content inside the "stack-list-template", nothing shows, so the content inside is permanently hidden. Also, all the code before the "script" that is in PHP is actually repeated a couple of times over, each one being a different query/stack.

Comment: jQuery's `toggle()` function works by going back and forth between display:none and display:block.  If setting display:none inline isn't working, then something else is wrong.

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda, here's a fiddle demonstrating your basic HTML structure working with the CSS rule I suggested:  https://jsfiddle.net/m8hf7gnd/

Comment: weird.. I put the exact same code you did and even if I clicked on the "accordion-header"s, no content would show.. They were hidden completely, I put the css as a <style> tag at the top of the page. BUT, when I removed the css, refreshing the page caused the accordion to automatically be open for every container. not closed by default.

Comment: Could this be a problem involving the jQuery version?

Comment: It's more likely to be an issue in the html generated by your php.  Hit F12 and examine the Elements tab, and see if anything looks odd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105052/discussion-between-noreceipt4panda-and-dave).

Comment: this could actually be a problem with the way that I'm calling my selector, what if it needs to be unique. as there are multiple accordion tabs, by hiding one, it could be becoming confused?